# Importing JSON Data to SQL using sqlalchemy python

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy

So I have a set of JSON files and would like to import them to my sqlite database using sqlalchemy.

The way that I am thinking is:

1. Declare a class in python with all the variable name:

   ```
   class Designs(Base):
     __tablename__='designs'
     __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}
     design_name= Column(String(80),nullable=False,primary_key=True)
     user_name= Column(String(80),nullable=False,primary_key=True)
     rev_tag= Column(String(80),nullable=False,primary_key=True)
    ...... much more variables.....
   ```
2. Read the JSON (using python json package and store it one by one)

   ```
   import json
   data = json.load(open('xxx.json'))
   for key, value in data.iteritems():
      store it in the sql database
   ```

But if my JSON file is very big, declaring all variables in the class seems very troublesome and hard to maintain as I plan to further grow my JSON file.

Wondering if there are any better way to do it

Comment: Do you mean that you expect to add and/or remove variables over time? Or just expand the data set? If you will just be expanding the data set, declaring all the variables shouldn't be a big deal. If you plan add or remove, you might think about using a document store (like Mongo) instead of an RDBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlalchemy offers a [mapping](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/mapping_styles.html#classical-mappings) interface in addition to the declarative interface you have shown.  Using it you can add columns programmaticly.

```
metadata = MetaData()

# This tuple of columns could be generated programmaticly
columns = (
    Column('design_name', String(80), primary_key=True),
    Column('user_name', String(80), nullable=False),
    Column('rev_tag', String(80), nullable=False),
    ...
)

designs = Table('designs', metadata, *columns)

class Designs(object):
    def __init__(self, json_data):    
      for key, value in data.iteritems():
        setattr(self, key, value)

mapper(Designs, designs)
```